# Auto suggest form in Twig file Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using Symfony2.3 for my project.
I want to add auto suggest functionality in our front-end
twig form Because in drop down list is very heavy like 20,000 data.
In all drop-down fields in front-end twig form.So I want to add auto
suggest functionality.

How I can do this ?
Any one know that because I do google but nothing found related twig.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GenemuFormBundle with jQuery UI autocomplete - https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle .

Full documentation is localized here - https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/autocomplete/index.md